# Plot lines in CESIUM AGI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cesiumjs

Can someone please help me in plotting a line in the cesium agi project. The line should be plotted in such a way that it should be from one part of the earth connecting to another part.

Answer (score 1):

The [Polylines demo](http://cesium.agi.com/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Polylines.html) shows how this is done.